# Smooth transition of wrapper when inner contents change dimentions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of elements that are contained within a wrapping div. The elements are toggled on and off and only one is shown at a time. The elements have different dimensions and when they get toggled the switch is really jerky.

Is it possible to have a smooth transition when the height of the wrapper div is changed?

It seems a little tricky because the wrapping div's height is only defined by the element that is contained within. From what I've seen, this means that normal css transitions can not smooth out the transition.

```js
$('.tile').hide();
$('.tile').eq(0).show();

var toggle = 1;

$('button').click(function(){
 if(toggle == 1){
  $('.tile').hide();
  $('.tile').eq(toggle).show();
  toggle = 0;
 }else{
  $('.tile').hide();
  $('.tile').eq(toggle).show();
  toggle = 1;
 }
});
```

```css
.tile{
 background-color:lightgreen;
 width:100px;height:100px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.tile:nth-child(2){
    background-color: orange;
 height:130px;
}

.wrap{
 background-color: lightblue;
 padding: 15px;
 float: left;
 transition: all .5s;
}

button{
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
 <div class="tile"></div>
 <div class="tile"></div>
</div>

<button>Swap</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This properly smooths the wrapper transition, but the big content overflows when it toggles.

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    //Fix the height to the current value
    $('.wrap').css('height', $('.wrap').height());
    //Toggle the contents
    $('.tile').toggleClass('hidden');
    //Set new height
    $('.wrap').animate({height: $('.tile:not(.hidden)').height()}, 0);
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/v3nLg257/4/

Comment: And the result looks even better if you add `overflow: hidden;` to the css of .wrap and and the jQuery animate time to `0`

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a different option, but I would recommend changing it around a bit to fit your process. I wrote a quick jsfiddle that should demonstrate how it works. But essentially, you are using jquery's `animate()` method to slow the transition between heights. As one shrinks, the other will expand and vice versa. Check it our [here](https://jsfiddle.net/04b2b1ex/). Make sure you abstract some of the process into separate functions. Use my code only as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to make it transition between two separate elements. Instead I would toggle between having a class on the `tile`. jQuery has a handy `toggleClass()` function so when the button is clicked it adds or removes the class as needed. Then just style the added class properly.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".tile").toggleClass("toggle")
});

.tile{
  background-color:lightgreen;
  width:100px;height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.tile.toggle{
  background-color: orange;
  height:130px;
}

.wrap{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

button{
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin:15px;
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>

<button>Swap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any class, on the same element, by the help of `jQuery.animate()` you can do something like this:

```js
var long = false;
$('button').click(function () {
     long = !long;
     if (long)
         $('div').animate({'height' : '+=50px'}, 500);
     else
         $('div').animate({'height' : '-=50px'}, 500);
  });
```

```css
div { height: 100px; width: 100px; border: solid 2px gray; background-color: beige }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<br><br>
<div>Div</div>
```

If you have separate elements, do like this:
 - Initially make both divs with same height
 - When click, hide the upper div, and animate height of second div
 - when click again, animate second div, then show first div